# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint, Id Colums not able generate by sequcece in Hibernat

Tags: postgresql

I am getting an error that Id column is not able to generate.

which will have the Getters and Setters.

**Note: In my case, Primary Key was bookingId**.

"Id" has to be a sequence number.

Below is the save method.
At the time of save is was not able to generate value for the column.

Below is My Entity.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "booking_id")
  private String bookingId;

  @Column(name = "booked_by")
  private String bookedBy;

  @Column(name = "booking_status")
  private int bookingStatus;

  @Column(name = "booking_rcv")
  private Date bookingRcv;

  @Column(name = "chargeable_kgs")
  private BigDecimal chargeableKgs;
}
```

Here we will have all the getters and setters, Constructors, hashcode, and equals methods.

```
@Transactional
  @Override
  public Booking saveBooking(Booking booking) {

    Booking savedBooking = bookingRepository.save(booking);

    if (savedBooking.getId() != null) {
      booking.setId(savedBooking.getId());
    }
    booking.setVersion(savedBooking.getVersion());
    bookingRepository.flush();
    // bookingRepository.refresh(booking);
    LOGGER.debug("savedbooking id::" + savedBooking.getId());
    return savedBooking;
  }
```

I am using postgre DB and Hibernate.

Comment: Why did you assign the `@Id` to the not generated column? This normally is the id column

Comment: Because in my case the primary key was bookingId column, not the Id. So I didn't defined id Column as  @Id.

Comment: You defined your Id, why don't you just remove the `long Id`? That will eliminate the error.

Comment: It has a lot of dependency on other classes. If I have to remove it then I have to change all the code in those classes that will affect the entaire application.

Comment: Why would you want an extra (unique, numeric) identifier, when your booking_id already is unique? Why don't you use that?

Comment: We have the liquibase scripts to create tables. its an old project. Previously it was EJB now we migrated to Hibernate. Before Migration Id column was able to generate. Now when we do the migration we are facing this issue.